# Reopen request 1803702

Tags: support, reopen-request

The question is closed as a duplicate of another question. I have highlighted the difference between the associated question and my question. I have now significantly edited the question to ask how old the CPU must actually be to pass the Windows 11 test?

[What will be a summary of whether the computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1803702/has-the-system-requirement-for-windows-11-changed-since-its-release-if-yes-wha)

Any chance this could be reviewed for reopening?

The question gets locked before I get the opportunity to type in what I think of. I have already thought better of my question.

This is what I actually want in the question:

Courtesy link: [Will my computer run Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11)

Prior to the actual release date, this has been the summary of whether the computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11.

> How do I get a summary of whether my computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11? There is a Microsoft App (PC Health Check), but I think WhyNotWin11 is more accurate:
>
> [Why Not Windows 11][8]
>
> Study the WhyNotWin11 README file, scroll down to the Download Latest Stable Release hyperlink, download and run it. You will see the dialog below:
>
> [![Why not Windows 11 screen][9]][9]
>
> You see in this screen CPU Generation. This screen came from my ThinkPad X1 laptop, and it meets all the requirements for Windows 11 except for CPU Generation.
>
> So far as I know now, the CPU must be newer than 3 years old to pass this Windows 11 test.
>
> We will not conclusively know an answer until closer to the official Windows 11 release date when clearer advice and test apps are available from Microsoft.
>
> I will typically purchase a commercial grade computer and so for me, four years is not particularly old, but apparently too old to run Windows 11.
>
> **This has been a summary to help us determine if our computers will run Windows 11.**
>
> **Follow up Note:**  I have today (June 28, 2021) installed Windows 11 Pro pre-release on my Windows Insider machine, and it is working well.

Now that is almost 2 years following the Windows 11 release date on October 5, 2021, Microsoft must have clearer advice and test apps. Now, what will be a clearer summary of whether the computer will be able to upgrade to Windows 11?

Note, I have made the edit. But, I have not submitted the question to the reopen queue. Instead, I am letting the community decide what to do.

Comment: Needs more information. Why is your question useful? Why do you think the requirements have changed? What extra information do you need that isn't provided by the duplicate? As it stands the only real answer is "No, requirements have not changed." So what exactly makes your question unique?

Comment: Your latest edit suggests that you think something significant might have changed as the requirements page was edited. You can click the "pencil" icon at the top of the page and it will take you to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-itpro-docs/blob/public/windows/whats-new/windows-11-requirements.md where you can see the history and changes. Just because a page on the internet is edited does not mean anything meaningful has changed and you still need to show why you think your question is distinct from the one already asked.

Comment: It is *constantly* being reviewed with each edit you make (it's starting to get a tad annoying if you ask me). But so far you haven't met the required amount of re-open votes and so it remains closed. Only if enough votes to re-open or I suppose an admin/moderator will get it re-opened. TBH I think it's answered by comments, duplicate and answers posted.

Comment: Indeed, the question has been submitted for review *at least* four times and each time has been left closed.

Comment: Aaaaaand here it is again https://imgur.com/a/4XmCtPb

Comment: The fact that you are obviously reading comments here and editing your question to incorporate them yet not engaging here to discus *why* your question should be reopened is somewhat curious.

Comment: Rather than constantly writing and rewriting your question you would do well to actually ***read*** the duplicate and follow the relevant links. The duplicate links to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/windows-11-requirements where the "compatible 64-bit processor" link on the processor requirements links to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements. That page will tell you everything about the exactly what processors are accepted. Again, *everything* you need can still be answered by the duplicate.

Comment: I have locked your question for now. You have made 18 edits and gone through the review queue 6 times. It does not need to keep going around in circles.

Comment: Arunabh Bhattacharya, also please do not contact me via the contact form on my website to ask about the status of your SuperUser question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question has been reviewed for reopening several times already.

- https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1210212
- https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1210213
- https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1210435
- https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1210471
- https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1210634

And is currently under review *again* right now.

- https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1210804

> The definition of ‘insanity’ is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results.

From my perspective your question needs a real reason to be reopened. In its original form it absolutely was a duplicate, and now it is nothing more than asking us to read documentation for you to find out if a duplicate is still valid.

That almost all of your edits are nothing more than slight rephrasing or copy-pastes of information elsewhere does not really change the fact that your basic question can be answered by the duplicate, or that the answers on the duplicate can be edited to incorporate new information.

You've shown no personal research or actual problem you are having, such as trying to run it on hardware you think *should* work and yet does not.

While "is this still valid?" can be a useful question after some significant length of time there should be a reason for it beyond curiosity and asking us to re-read documentation for you.

As a duplicate your question will not be deleted, and you have an answer. If that is not enough then you need to tell us why it should be reopened instead of abusing the reopen review system.

Comment: The fact the answer that was submitted, suggests the requirements have not changed, strongly support NOT reopening the question.  If the question were to be reopened, not only would this question have to be anwered, so would the existing question have to be updated. As a community we don't need multiple questions, all with the answer, that only exist because of time passage. If anything based on recent reports, the requirements for Windows 10, if they do change will become stricter. It is rumored, that Windows 12 (rumor itself) won't have anyway, to bypass requirements like Secure Boot or TPM